# jquery Event fire just while scrolling?

Tags: jquery

i use jQuery to show after time then hide when scrolling, but cannot.
I want event just fire while Scrolling.
See this , i scrolled, but event still...

`$('#target').scroll(function() {   $('#log').fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut();
 });`

http://jsfiddle.net/VbcKv/

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you can use a timer to control the frequency of scroll event as shown below

```
$('#log').hide()

var timer;
$('#target').scroll(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#log').stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut();
    }, 200)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mbeXV/)

Comment: thank, i've tryed your code, but after a time i scrolling, the hide Element is fadeIn about 2-3 seconds and hide, not 5s, and while user scrolling, the #log is still hide
i Want Event Just Fire AFTER user is stop scrolling,that means WHILE user is scrolling, the #log not hide, when user stop scrolling, and after 5s, it will hide .